# What does `flush_cache_xxx` in linux kernel do?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

When I check permanent mapping high memory in linux kernel 2.6.11, I find kernel will periodically flush high memory cache and tlbs to allocate new entries for temporary mapping. Flush tlb invalidates virtual->physical map, but what does flush cache mean?

I try to look up [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/core-api/cachetlb.html).

> these routines must be implemented for cpus which have virtually indexed caches which must be flushed when virtual–>physical translations are changed or removed.

As one example mentioned in that doc, `flush_cache_mm` is used when `exit` or `exec`. I wonder if `flush_cache_xxx` means

1. flushing cache to force a page table (tlb) check next time accessing so that kernel can get the right page descriptor (VIVT cache).
2. freeing cache line which used to fill with old unusable page (VI cache). The reason here is if kernel don't flush, later a different virtual address which refer to the same old page frame may index to a different cache line. Thus the old cache line which may have recent changes is lost.